# My program doesn't print anything for the print("the"). Can anyone explain why?

Tags: python

```
file = open("newfile.txt","w") 

file.write("Hello World") 
file.write("This is my text file") 
file.write("and the day is nice.")  
file.close() 

file= open("newfile.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if "the" in "newfile.txt":
        print("the")
```

So, what I want it to do, is to print "the" once, as "the" appears in my file once. Why isn't it doing it???

Comment: is "the" in "newfile.txt"?

Comment: Hint: `"the" in "newfile.txt"` checks if string `the` is part of string `newfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "the" in "newfile.txt":
    print("the")
```

The if statement here verifies whether string literal "the" is in another string literal "newfile.txt", and it's clearly false, so nothing is printed.

For your purpose and to be more pythonic file operations, consider using the **with** statement as following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

filename = 'newfile.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write("Hello World\n")
    f.write("This is my text file\n")
    f.write("and the day is nice.\n")

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'the' in line:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `"the" in "Newfile.txt"`, but `"the" in lines[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "the" in "newfile.txt":
    print("the")
```

You are verifying if there is a substring `"the"` in the string `newfile.txt`.

Use `if "the" in file:` for the whole file

Or, `if "the" in lines[i]:`, for just that line

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
if "the" in "newfile.txt":
```

It tries to find "the" in "newfile.txt" string, not in the file. You probably want to find it in the line, so fix it like this:

```
if "the" in lines[i]:
```

It compares all lines and prints "the" when it's found.